# how will my switch condition statement work properly?

Tags: javascript

I ve got a tic tac toe game in my code. for the first try i use a IF a then it works good. So i try to use too a SWITCH and then that my code doesn't work properly and i ve got always scores: You loose so that mean I ve got always DEFAULT result. I dont know why

```
function checkResult(player,ai) {

    switch(player,ai) {
        case(player === ai):
        console.log(`draws`);
        break;
        case((player === 'paper'&& ai === 'rock') || (player === 'rock' && ai === 'nożyczki') || (player === 'scisors' && ai ==='paper')):
        console.log('You win Basterd');
        break;
        default:
        console.log(`you loose`);

    }
    // if(player === ai) {
    //     console.log('draws');
    // } else if ((player === 'paper'&& ai === 'rock') || (player === 'rock' && ai === 'nożyczki') || (player === 'scisors' && ai ==='paper')) {
    //     console.log('you win Basterd');
    // } else {
    //     console.log(`you loose`);
    // }
    hands.forEach(hand => hand.style.boxShadow = '');
}
```

hi. Im doing a tic tac toe game. For the first time i did it with IF Statement. Then i try to use switch either. But it doesn't work. In console i just see the default score : You loose.

Comment: You can't pass multiple parameters to `switch`, you can either switch on player or ai, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way:

```
function checkResult(player,ai) {
        switch(true) {
            case player === ai:
            console.log(`draws`);
            break;
            case player === 'paper' && ai === 'rock':
            case player === 'rock' && ai === 'nożyczki':
            case player === 'scisors' && ai === 'paper':
            console.log('You win Basterd');
            break;
            default:
            console.log(`you loose`);

        }
    }
```